# Algolia rails gem multiple geolocations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, algolia

It's [possible](https://www.algolia.com/doc/geo-search/geo-search-overview#importing-data) to use multiple locations for an object. How can you do this using the [rails gem](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-rails#geo-search)?

I've tried

```
 geoloc :lat, :lon
 geoloc :lat2, :lon2
```

but only one location is saved

I've also tried

```
geoloc do
  _geoloc
end

def _geoloc
 [latitude, longitude, 64.2008, 149.4937]
end
```

but the geoloc fx is expecting 2 arguments `geoloc: wrong number of arguments (0 for 2) (ArgumentError)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like the Rails gem `geoloc` helper supports multiple entries right now. You might be able to work around it by directly registering an attribute named `_geoloc` and implementing it as a helper method that can return multiple locations:

```
algoliasearch do

  attributes :_geoloc

  def _geoloc
    [{ "lat": 47.279430, "lng": 5.106450 },
     { "lat": 47.293228, "lng": 5.004570 },
     { "lat": 47.316669, "lng": 5.016670 }]
  end

end
```

If you try this, make sure to remove the original `geoloc` call so it doesn't override the data you're manually setting.